# Weird characters result from reading/writing

Tags: java, file, text, character

I wrote some simple Java code to read in strings from a text file, combine them, and write them back out. (See snippet below for a simplified version with no change in output)

The problem is that particular characters (- and ...) are different in the input file and the output file.  The dashes and ellipsis show up as special, unreadable characters in the output file.  I did not intend to change them, and I think there is some particular encoding I should use to avoid this.

I am running under Windows.  The weird characters show up in multiple editors (NotePad, WordPad, and Word) in place of the dashes and ellipsis.

```
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
String line;
while ((line=inFile.readLine()) != null)
{
     out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Not enough information without the format of the input file

Comment: The weird characters you use are far beyond the 255 codepoints of ASCII encoding. For example `...` (horizontal ellipsis) is mapped to Unicode codepoint 2606 (in hex) and no equivalent ASCII representation for it. Try to use a Unicode font in your editor of your choice (NotePad, WordPad, and Word, Eclipse) for you to be able to see them correctly.

Comment: The characters show up normally in the input file.  Once I read it into a Java string and write out that string to an output file, then they look like special characters.  I would simply like to write them out as they originally were.

Answer (score 2):

**REVISION**

Your input is on `ANSI  windows-1252`

So this should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File f = new File("in.txt");
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, Charset.forName("windows-1252")));
        String x;
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("testing.txt")));

        while((x = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.write(x);
            writer.newLine();
        }

        writer.close();
}
```

Comment: No, it's two particular characters, dashes and ellipsis, that are weird after I read them into a string.

Comment: Then I refer you to my comment in your question, we don't know what type of encoding/format you are using in your input.

Comment: Yes. I don't have control of input file.  Will post it later.

Comment: How do I attach a file here?   Sorry, but I can`t find a way.

Comment: @user1704891 Use a file upload service and post the link on your question

Comment: The file is at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/109170884/in.txt.  I narrowed it down to the two troublesome characters.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what i did was:

- First, i figure what was the encoding desired, in my case i was editing an existing file and to know what was its encoding, i type the next command

  > file --mime-encoding in.txt
- Then knowing what was the encoding standard you should create the BufferedWriter and the BufferedReader with the same standard

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      File f = new File("in.txt");
      FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(f);
      InputStreamReader conexion = new InputStreamReader(stream,"ISO-8859-1");
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(conexion);
      String x;

      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("in.txt"),"ISO-8859-1");

      while((x = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          writer.write(x);
          writer.newLine();
      }

      writer.close();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using MimeType in the BufferedReader as below:

```
    InputStream myFileStream = new FileInputStream("in.txt");
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myFileStream , "utf-8"));
```

If above doesn't help, try changing the mime type values to other mime types e.g. "utf-8". If still doesn't work, please share your "in.txt" file.